# alternative to breakOut that is less verbose

Tags: scala

breakOut is nice, but too verbose:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map{i => (i * 2, i / 2.0, i.toString)}(breakOut) : Array[(Int, Double, String)]
```

I don't want to specify the element type. I want something like:

```
 List(1, 2, 3).map{i => (i * 2, i / 2.0, i.toString)}(build[Array])
```

I can write a `buildArray` easily, but then I'd need a buildSet, buildList, etc. So I want something generic.

Extra points ( ;-) ) if you can make it work for Map (using the same name `build`, not build2 or buildMap)

Comment: [This is](http://pastebin.com/rsmFtqdt) not what you want, but I guess it's the best you can get. This will not work for `String` or `Map`.

Comment: Yes, it is what I wanted. I did the same, but got the generic parameters mixed (used T in def and A in code) and couldn't figure it out from the compiler error.

Comment: @senia Maybe make it an answer?

Comment: Btw, would be nice to remove the empty parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work for `String` or `Map`. Also this code requires `scala.language.higherKinds`:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.breakOut

class Build[To[_]]

def build[To[_]] = new Build[To]

implicit def buildToCbf[From, T, To[_]](b: Build[To])
                                       (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing,T,To[T]]): CanBuildFrom[From,T,To[T]] =
  collection.breakOut

List(1, 2, 3).map{i => (i * 2, i / 2.0, i.toString)}(build[Array])
//res0: Array[(Int, Double, String)] = Array((2,0.5,1), (4,1.0,2), (6,1.5,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Senia's solution is great. Unfortunately as he mentioned this won't work for `Map` nor `String`.
Here is another alternative (based on his solution), that does:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.breakOut

class Build[To]

def build[TargetSuperType] = new Build[TargetSuperType]

implicit def buildToCbf[From, T, TargetSuperType, To<:TargetSuperType](b: Build[TargetSuperType])
                                       (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing,T,To]): CanBuildFrom[From,T,To] =
  collection.breakOut

List(1, 2, 3).map{i => (i * 2, i / 2.0, i.toString)}(build[Array[_]])
//res0: Array[(Int, Double, String)] = Array((2,0.5,1), (4,1.0,2), (6,1.5,3))

List(1, 2, 3).map{i => (i * 2, i.toString)}(build[Map[_,_]])
//res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 6 -> 3)

List('a', 'b', 'c').map(_.toUpper)(build[String])
//res2: String = ABC
```

This is little more verbose because now you don't just do `build[Array]`, but `build[Array[_]]`. In exchange you get the ability to specify any target collection you want, irrespective of the number of type arguments (such as `Map` and `String`).

Plus you can still be fully explicit (similarly to when using `breakOut`) if you choose to:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map{i => (i * 2, i / 2.0, i.toString)}(build[Array[(Int, Double, String)]])
res3: Array[(Int, Double, String)] = Array((2,0.5,1), (4,1.0,2), (6,1.5,3))
```

All that with the same syntax (in other words, using the same name `build`, as you requested)